# why alpha and Constraint constant location are different in Animation block

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to understand Animation in iOS

if i want to change view's heightConstraint i set code like this

```
@objc func handleAnimatioButtonTapped(){
  targetViewHeightConstraint.constant = 200
  UIView.animated(2) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
}
```

I read about `layoutIfNeeded()` and `setNeedsLayout`, async and sync

but when i want change alpha

why the code looks like this?

```
@objc func handleAnimatioButtonTapped(){
  UIView.animated(2) {
    self.targetView.alpha = 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call layoutIfNeeded() or any other functions because you are not updating the layout/position of anything, just the view's alpha value.

Comment: is it related with three steps to laying out and redrawing views in Auto Layout?

Comment: What are you referring to with 'three steps'.